# performcallback gridview after combobox filtering

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, combobox, devexpress

can you help me to fix my problem, I made gridview, and I use combobox to filter data in gridview and get gridview performcallback after filter, but gridview not callback after filter. how can I do ? Help me Please?
this is some code :
controller gridview filter :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FilterTypePro(String typePro)
        {
            //Session["typePro"] = typePro;
            var model = Model._ProposalObject.ListDataProposal();

            if (typePro != null && typePro != string.Empty)
            {
                model = Model._ProposalObject.ListDataProposal(typePro);
            }

            return PartialView("_gvPartialViewProposals", model);
        }
```

and this is code to get value filter combobox :

```
    function OnClickFilter(type) {
        type = cbTypeProposal.GetValue();     
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("FilterTypePro", "App")',
            data: { 'typePro': type },
            success: function (data) {
                /*gvPartialViewProposals.AdjustControl();
                try {
                    gvPartialViewProposals.PerformCallback();
                }
                catch(er){
                }*/
                gvPartialViewProposals.Refresh(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is code to view cshtml :

```
groupItem.Items.Add(item =>
            {
                    item.Caption = "Type Of Proposal";
                    item.Width = 400;
                    item.SetNestedContent(() =>
                    {
                        ViewContext.Writer.Write("<table><tr><td>");
                        Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(cmbSettings =>
                        {
                            cmbSettings.Name = "cbTypeProposal";
                            cmbSettings.Width = 100;
                            cmbSettings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
                            cmbSettings.ShowModelErrors = true;
                            cmbSettings.Properties.Items.Add("ATL", "ATL");
                            cmbSettings.Properties.Items.Add("BTL", "BTL");
                            cmbSettings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e) { OnClickFilter();}";
                        }).Render();
                        ViewContext.Writer.Write("</td></tr></table>");
                    });
                }); ;
        }).GetHtml();
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your javascript function as follows:

```
function OnClickFilter(type){
    type = cbTypeProposal.GetValue(); 
    gvPartialViewProposals.PerformCallback({
        'typePro': type
    });
}
```

Modify your grid settings as follows:

```
settings.Name = "gvPartialViewProposals";
settings.CustomActionRouteValues = new { Controller = "App", Action = "FilerTypePro" };
```

Comment: thank you about answer, but I have fixed my problem.